# Azure pipeline CMD fail to stop Windows Servce

Tags: .net, cmd, windows-services, azure-pipelines

In Azure Pipeline I use self hosted agent and on the machine I have manualy installed windows service and started it. It works locally fine. But in the pipeline when i try to stop it (in order to update the DLL`s) the task CMD always crahses with same error:

[image]

It just cant find the windows service, which is installed and working properly.

[image]

In the CMD task on Azure pipeline the code is just that:

> net stop RemindersService
>   [image]

I tried every idea a haved: tried from PowerShell, tried from some add on on Azure, tried to set service logon account (set machine administrator) and result is every time the same.

Anyone fought with this?

Comment: when configuring the service logon account to have administrator's permission, are you using this [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#unattended-config) how to set the service account?

Comment: output of ".\run --diagnostics"  to see if your configuration is expected.

Comment: Diagnostics seem OK https://pastebin.com/GubyTCP3. I have configured the Azure Agent manually from the same guide just NOT using Unattended way. Build, deploy and everything other works fine. Only the services not

Answer (score 1):

I have founded the problem.

Azure Agent was configured poperly, but I was trying to STOP and START services in the Release pipeline. Once I moved the scripts in the build pipeline it all run smootly.

Comment: is your release pipeline also runs on that same agent?

Comment: I guess so. I have only one active Azure Agent.

Comment: so you installed the "self-hosted agent" on your target server.  When doing yaml based build (Azure pipeline), it works, but in classical release pipeline using same agent it does not.  I want to see if i can re-create this on my Azure env by creating a self-hosted agent against my dev vm over the weekend.

Comment: My bad, there is another agent used only for Release, it is just not in the Default Pool. However when I Run diagnostics on this agent: "WRITE ERROR: Unrecognized command-line input arguments: 'diagnostics'."